# select an element with (x,y) coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there a way to select an element using it's (x,y) coordinates with jquery or in any other way. other than going through all the page elements and comparing coordinates.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  The answer is no - sort of.  However, depending on what you want to do, there might be better ways around that.  Getting the coordinates of a clicked element...  ...or getting the coordinates of a known element, or moving a known element to specific coordinates, et cetera.

Comment: vanilla javascript has an elementFromPoint() API. The problem is, support for this seems to vary between browsers.  Check this page where someone has provided a consistent way to do it using jQuery -- http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `document.elementFromPoint()`.  Note that this is not jQuery specific.  Reference and compatibility guidance on [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#documentview).

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution/), works cross browser

Comment: Note that browser compatibility issues are only present in Opera 10.10 and Safari 4, both antiquated versions at this point.

Comment: Depends on your target audience. Safari 4 will be present on legace iPhones.